# Is there an equivalent for shouldSelectViewController in android for BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, bottomnavigationview

I have a BottomNavigationView in my android activity, which consists of 4 menuItem. When I tap on the downloads menu I check if there are any downloaded contents available, if available I will allow the navigation to happen and if there is no downloaded content I will show a Toast stating the same and I want the previous tab to remain selected. In iOS I can use the delegate method shouldSelectViewController to determine whether navigation can be allowed or not.
The method signature is specified below:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

I tried reselecting the previously selected tab, as a result, the previous item is retained but the selected item color is still assigned to the downloads tab.

```
    private void BottomNavigationItemSelected(object obj, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs args)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment currentFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.content_frame);
        string title = "";
        if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_explore)
        {
            _selectedToolbarId = args.Item.ItemId;
            title = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.shelf_title);
            fragment = _exploreFragment;
            _fragmentTag = "Home";
        }
        else
        {
            title = args.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString();
        }
        if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_dashboard)
        {
            //COULD BE MADE CONFIGURABLE
            //fragment = _dashboardFragment;
            _selectedToolbarId = args.Item.ItemId;
            fragment = _redesignDashboard;
            _fragmentTag = "Dashboard";
        }
        else if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_more)
        {
            _selectedToolbarId = args.Item.ItemId;
            fragment = _moreFragment;
            _fragmentTag = "More";
        }
        else if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_report)
        {
            _selectedToolbarId = args.Item.ItemId;
            fragment = _reportFragment;
            _fragmentTag = "Report";
        }
        else if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_downloads)
        {
            List<Product> _downloadProducts = DBService.GetDB().GetDownloadedProducts();
            if (_downloadProducts == null || _downloadProducts.Count == 0)
            {
                _bottomNavigationView.SelectedItemId = _selectedToolbarId;
                Toast.MakeText(this, "No downloaded products", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                args.Item.SetChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                _downloadGalleryFragment = new DownloadGalleryFragment(_downloadProducts);
                fragment = _downloadGalleryFragment;
                _fragmentTag = "Downloads";
            }
        }
        if (fragment != null)
        {
            _toolbarTitle.Text = title;
            ToggleTitle(true);
            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.fab_slide_in_from_right, Resource.Animation.fab_slide_out_to_left).Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment, _fragmentTag).Commit();
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_explore"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="@string/explore"
      android:icon="@drawable/explore_icon"
      app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_dashboard"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="@string/dashboard"
      android:icon="@drawable/Dashboard_new_icon"
      app:showAsAction="always" />

     <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_report"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="@string/reports"
      android:icon="@drawable/dashboard_icon"
      app:showAsAction="always" />

     <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_downloads"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="@string/menu_downloads"
      android:icon="@drawable/download_icon"
      app:showAsAction="always" />

     <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_more"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:title="@string/more_bottombar"
      android:icon="@drawable/more_icon"
      app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Do you want some condition to be fulfilled before you switch in between tabs?

Comment: @G.hakim yes. yes, only if a condition is satisfied I want the switch to that specific tab to happen, else already selected tab should remain selected.

Comment: Are you using it with a viewpager?

Comment: @G.hakim using BottomNavigationView with a frame in the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is an issue with Android or the Bottom Navigation View. When I executed the reselection of the previous fragment after a small delay of 50milliseconds its working fine. ie the reselected fragment or the previous fragments icon gets highlighted as required.

```
if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_downloads)
            {
                List<Product> _downloadProducts = DBService.GetDB().GetDownloadedProducts();
                if (_downloadProducts == null || _downloadProducts.Count == 0)
                {

                   _readProgressTimerTask = new Timer
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Interval = 50,
                        AutoReset = false
                    };
                    _readProgressTimerTask.Elapsed += OnProgressCheckTimeElapsed;
                    Toast.MakeText(this, this.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.no_downloads), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    _downloadGalleryFragment = new DownloadGalleryFragment(_downloadProducts);
                    fragment = _downloadGalleryFragment;
                    _fragmentTag = "Downloads";
                }
            }

private void OnProgressCheckTimeElapsed(System.Object source, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                _bottomNavigationView.SelectedItemId = _selectedToolbarId;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such delegate that works as `shouldSelectViewController` but what you can do is get the menu items of the bottom nav bar and disables these menu items:

Something like this:

```
var listMenuItems = new List<IMenuItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < bottomNav.Menu.Size(); i++)
{
   listMenuItems.Add(bottomNav.Menu.GetItem(i));
}
```

Once you have them here you can manipulate them as you like, to enable or disable an item just use the `SetEnabled` method that takes a `boolean` as a parameter.

Comment: The problem is that decision making is dynamic and we always want the menu item to be there. Whenever we click the item am checking the criteria to show the corresponding fragment. If the criteria is not met am resetting the selectedItem of BottomNavigationView. But the problem is required fragment is loaded but the red selected color still remains with the one user tapped instead of being on the one I reselected programatically

Comment: From API 25.3.0 they have introduced the method `SetSelectedItemId(int id)` which let's you mark an item as selected as if it was tapped.

Comment: Dude that's what I have already mentioned in the code. I am reselecting the required tab using selecteditemid and as a result the required tab gets selected but the corresponing tabs icon doesnt get selected. 
_bottomNavigationView.SelectedItemId = _selectedToolbarId;

Comment: Did you check whether or not it has the right item id or not? I have a feeling it does not!

Comment: Yes, I checked its the right id, moreover, if it was wrong the fragment in the frame would have changed.

Comment: Can you add the items's xml file that you used in your BottomNavigationView

Comment: Added the menu xml

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you first read the guideline [available here](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#) to implement bottom navigation **for android**.

That what you want doesn't make much sense, an empty screen should be shown saying something like "There is not content available" or the message you like.

In this link [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView#setonnavigationitemreselectedlistener) you can find all public methods and listeners you can set to bottom navigation. As for your case, you might be interested in adding these two.

**setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener()**

**setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()**

Best regards, Pedro.